# Manipulating UIImage with GestureRecognizers - NOT UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Using Gesture Recognizers such as Pan, Pinch, and Rotate, is it at all possible to manipulate a UIImage within a UIImageView?

Whenever I try to define the gesture recognizer for the UIImage, I get an error stating

> No visible UIImage supports 'addGestureRecognizer:'

With this code:

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateImage:)];
[imageStrip addGestureRecognizer:rotateGesture];
```

Is there anyway to transform a UIImage inside of a UIImageView without transforming the UIImageView?

Comment: Actually, modifying the image data itself could be such a complicated thing... 

Why is that you don't want to transform the UIImageView? I ask it because you have the possibility to generate a new UIImage from any UIView (something like taking a snapshot), and may be it would be ok for you.

Comment: I was aiming for a special edit effect in my application, which I ended up using a UIView with the transformable UIImageView inside of it. Then I set the `clipsToBounds = YES`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add gesture recognizers to any kind of `UIView` and in your event handling methods you could redraw `UIImage` to a freshly created `CGContextRef`. This context would have to be transformed with `CGContextRotateCTM`, `CGContextScaleCTM` , `CGContextTranslateCTM` that would be called with parameters matching the ones you receive from gesture recognizers. That's the hard way.

Alternatively you could create a scratch `UIImageView` with your image, transform it with gesture recognizers then render it to a `CGContextRef` and get the transformed image out of this context.

Certainly doable, but not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

`UIGestureRecognizer` can only be attached to a `UIView` - `UIImage` is not a descendant of `UIView`.

This is because an `UIView` (or it's descendant)  can receive touches - `UIImage` can not.

Please see [Gestures Recognizers Are Attached to a View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW10).

You could recalculate/rerender the `UIImage` based on parameters after user is done manipulating it. On how to do this: it really depends on what you want to achieve.